# Lua-style in Python

Tags: python, lua

Variable a doesn't exist

I can write in Lua language:

```
a = (a or 0) + 1
```

Now a = 1

this allows me not to declare the variable "a" in advance. This is analog of

```
a = 0
a = a + 1
```

How can I do the same in Python?

```
a = (a or 0) + 1
```

P.S. Why is it important? To avoid assign zero to variables:

python (4 lines of code):

```
for ticker in ticker_list:
    total_volume[ticker] = 0

for a in range (1,10):
    total_volume[ticker] = total_volume[ticker] + a
```

lua (2 lines of code):

```
for a=1,9 do:
    total_volume[ticker] = (total_volume[ticker] or 0) + a
```

Comment: I suppose `a = (None or 0) + 1`would do what you want, but I cannot see a use-case.

Comment: What's the benefit of doing that rather than your first approach of defining `a=0` ?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh dear friend it saves many lines of code

Comment: if a is being passed as a parameter to a function, you can do `def f(a=0): ` for eg.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke I've edited question to answer You

Comment: @IgorK.: "*dear friend it saves many lines of code*" It saves exactly one line of code. You could easily declare a local variable in the loop which contains either the value or 0 if the value were none, then add one to the local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does have a ternary operator, like Lua and many other languages

But unlike Lua, Python does not handle an undefined variable as a "false" value, it will throw an error if you attempt to evaluate an undefined variable. Specifically in your case you will get a key error for the key `ticker` not being present.

Lua Ternary:

```lua
    total_volume[ticker] = (total_volume[ticker] or 0) + a
```

Python Equivalent:

```py
    total_volume[ticker] = (total_volume[ticker] if ticker in total_volume else 0) + a
```

Where Lua will pass you the value before the `or` if it is `truthy`, python will pass you the value before the `if` when the statement that follows is `true`, and the value after the `else` when it is `false`.

To safely evaluate if the key was in the dictionary we can use `in`.

This is mostly to demonstrate the ternary operation you were using in Lua and how to do it in Python, but that doesn't mean it is the right tool for this problem.

---

A cleaner solution I would suggest:

```py
   total_volume[ticker] = total_volume.get(ticker, 0) + 1
```

It is less code and easier to reason about. `get` will return `total_volume[ticker]` or if the key is not present in the dictionary it will return the default value, `0`.

Comment: Thank You! Which of them is faster? It is important for me because I use it in millions lines of datafiles.

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, I would suggest to use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
d["counter"] += 5
print(d.items()) # output: dict_items([('counter', 5)])
```

## BUT -

I don't think it's a good practice but you can use `locals()` or `globals()` to access variables dynamically in the desired scope:

```
a = 1
print(locals().get("a")) # ouput:1

c = locals().get("c", 2) + 1 
print(c) # output 3
```

Comment: There is also the possibility of doing it with a standard dict: `d["counter"] = d.get("counter", 0) + 5`